# WIX custom action data is blank in installuisequence

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I can see that the dll is getting called and it's the right entry point at the right time but none of the session data is empty.  This is driving me nuts!

please, anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

here are the WIX definitions

```
    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.BinariesForWix)blah.blah.CA.dll"  />

    <CustomAction Id="OptionsFileFound" Return="check" Property="OptionsFileFound.Get" Value="file=[OPTIONSPATH],version=[INSTALLVERSION],ADVANCED=[ADVANCED],parmsetting=OPTIONSEXIST"/>
    <CustomAction Id="OptionsFileFound.Get" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="OptionsFileFound" Execute="immediate" HideTarget="no" Return="check"/>  

    <InstallUISequence>
       <!-- check if installation configuration file is present -->
       <Custom Action ="OptionsFileFound.Get" After="MigrateFeatureStates"></Custom>
       <Custom Action ="AbortError" After="OptionsFileFound.Get">NOT(OPTIONSEXIST="yes")</Custom>
       <Custom Action ="InstallDatabaseList.Get" After="OptionsFileFound.Get"></Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>
```

and now for the c# code

```
     [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult OptionsFileFound(Session session)
    {
        FetchParms parmSet = new FetchParms(session);

        fileLocation = parmSet.GetActData("file");
        version = parmSet.GetActData("version");
        olympicInstall = parmSet.GetActData("advanced");

        session.Log(string.Format("*************************************************       Looking for options file at {0}, version number should be {1}", fileLocation, version));

        string parmSetting = parmSet.GetActData("parmsetting");

        if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
        {
            fileExists = true;
            session.Log("*************************************************                  found xml options file");
            LoadXmlToDictionary(fileLocation, session);
            session.Log("*************************************************                  loaded xml options file");
        }
        else
        {
            fileExists = false;
        }

        session[parmSetting] = fileExists ? "yes" : "no";

        parmSet.Dispose();
        parmSet = null;

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

// fetch parms class here

```
     public FetchParms(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("*************************************************  creating parameter dictionary");
        session.Log("*************************************************  session data = " + session.CustomActionData.Count.ToString());
        CustomActionData parmSets = session.CustomActionData;
        string parmString = parmSets.ToString();
        session.Log("************************************************* passed custom action data = " + session.CustomActionData.ToString());
        string[] eachParm = parmString.Split(new char[] { ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string theParm in eachParm)
        {
            string[] theOptions = theParm.Split(new char[] { '=' });

            this.parmList.Add(theOptions[0], string.IsNullOrEmpty(theOptions[1]) ? string.Empty : theOptions[1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

CustomActionData is for deferred custom actions.  Deferred custom actions can only exist in the InstallExecuteSequence between the InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize standard actions.  Trying to use them in the UI sequence is incorrect.

Comment: Please provide an alternative if it does not bother you!

Comment: It's not that it "bothers" me... it's simply not possible to schedule deferred custom actions in the UI sequence.  The MSI SDK doesn't support that.